# Generate randomised columns with parametric names in table postgres9.3

Tags: postgresql, loops, random, parameters, postgresql-9.3

**UPDATE:** I was looking for an intersection of sets that do not intersect, thus updated the original table file. Like in my big dataset each lot has all the timestamps `dt` available. My version still doesn't work though...

I am analysing whether distance to closest vehicle has an impact on probability to call. For that I have *real* data, and I would like to generate *"fake"* data by randomising results `n` times. In the *fake* randomised set there should be no correlation by definition. Then I compare the *real* to the *fake* data as my benchmark.

### Problem:

I am looking for advice on the way to do this in Postgres 9.3. Currently I am trying to use a function that gets as a parameter the number of randomised columns `n`.

The input `small_panel` table is derived from real observations and has lots with `lotid`, a column `called = 1` if the lot called and `NULL` if did not, and a column `distance` with various values. I want to generate `n` columns (`called_1, called_2, ... ,called_n`) with randomised lots `lotid` selected but for each time period `dt` having the same number of calls.

For example, in the table there are 2 calls with timestamp `dt = 2009-06-05 22:30:00` so I would like to still have 2 calls with that timestamp but randomise which lots placed the calls in each *fake* column.

I would greatly appreciate your input.

### Data to try:

The toy table here is small (15 rows) but the ones I have to deal with are large (e.g. 3 million rows) so if it is too slow I might need to optimise later.

The original input table `small_panel` looks like this (I have put a csv and a pgsql file to create the table and my not working function [here](https://github.com/lizardie/Stackexchange_Q_pgpsql)):

```
select * from small_panel order by dt;

  gid   |  id  | lotid  | called | distance |         dt          
--------+------+--------+--------+----------+---------------------
 536596 |  207 |   2904 |        |  392.648 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00
 538417 | 2025 | 230328 |      1 |  69.9698 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00
 537409 | 1017 |   5453 |      1 |  190.071 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00
 629637 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  226.278 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00
 630647 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  387.914 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00
 628826 |  207 |   2904 |      1 |  439.769 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00
 644185 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  124.361 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00
 645195 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  214.799 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00
 643377 |  207 |   2904 |      1 |  8.50651 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00
 670887 | 1017 |   5453 |      1 |  81.0408 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00
 671896 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  193.953 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00
 670076 |  207 |   2904 |        |  135.042 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00
 679781 |  207 |   2904 |        |  170.979 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00
 680594 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  223.304 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00
 681605 | 2025 | 230328 |      1 |  92.0443 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00
(15 rows)
```

### Solution - try :

I tried the following function (without inner loop, almost working but wrong results):

```
DROP FUNCTION ib_randomise_calls(int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ib_randomise_calls ( n INT DEFAULT 3 ) 
RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
  DECLARE mytext TEXT DEFAULT 'small_panel';
  DECLARE r record;
BEGIN

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000;
  CREATE TABLE panel_000 AS ( SELECT * FROM small_panel  );
  ALTER TABLE panel_000 ADD COLUMN calledz INT;

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000_times;
  CREATE TABLE panel_000_times AS ( SELECT distinct on (dt) * FROM panel_000 where called is not null );

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000_lots;
  CREATE TABLE panel_000_lots AS ( SELECT distinct lotID FROM panel_000 order by 1);    

  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP

      RAISE NOTICE 'i: %', i;
      EXECUTE format( $x1$ ALTER TABLE panel_000 ADD COLUMN called_%1$s INT; $x1$, i);

      UPDATE panel_000 a SET calledZ = 1  
          from panel_000_times b , panel_000_lots c
          where a.dt = b.dt
          AND a.lotid IN (  select lotID from panel_000_lots  
                            order by random() 
                            limit (select count(*) from panel_000 d where called=1 and a.dt=d.dt)   ) ;

      EXECUTE format( 
      $x2$ 
        UPDATE panel_000 a SET called_%1$s = 1  
            from panel_000_times b , panel_000_lots c
            where a.dt = b.dt
            AND a.lotid IN (  select lotID from panel_000_lots  
                              order by random() 
                              limit (select count(*) from panel_000 d where called=1 and a.dt=d.dt)   ) ;
      $x2$, i);    

  END LOOP ;
  RETURN mytext;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select ib_randomise_calls(4);
```

Which produces the columns but with wrong results (different number of calls for each timestamp `dt`):

```
select dt, count(*), count(distinct lotid) lots , sum(called) calls, sum(calledz) cz, sum(called_1) c1, sum(called_2) c2, sum(called_3) c3, sum(called_4) c4 from panel_000 group by 1 order by 1;

         dt          | count | lots | calls | cz | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 
---------------------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+----+----
 2009-06-05 12:40:00 |     3 |    3 |     2 |  3 |  3 |  2 |  1 |  2
 2009-06-05 19:00:00 |     3 |    3 |     1 |  3 |    |  1 |  1 |  1
 2009-06-05 20:00:00 |     3 |    3 |     1 |  2 |    |  2 |  1 |  1
 2009-06-05 21:50:00 |     3 |    3 |     1 |  3 |  2 |    |    |  2
 2009-06-05 22:30:00 |     3 |    3 |     1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  1 |  1
(5 rows)

 select 'TOT               .' as dt,count(*), count(distinct lotid) lots , sum(called) calls, sum(calledz) cz, sum(called_1) c1, sum(called_2) c2, sum(called_3) c3, sum(called_4) c4 from panel_000;
         dt          | count | lots | calls | cz | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 
---------------------+-------+------+-------+----+----+----+----+----
 TOT               . |    15 |    3 |     6 | 12 |  7 |  8 |  4 |  7
(1 row)

select lotid, count(*) , sum(called) calls, sum(calledz) cz, sum(called_1) c1, sum(called_2) c2, sum(called_3) c3, sum(called_4) c4  from panel_000 group by 1 order by 1;

 lotid  | count | calls | cz | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 
--------+-------+-------+----+----+----+----+----
   2904 |     5 |     2 |  5 |  3 |  3 |    |  3
   5453 |     5 |     2 |  4 |  1 |  3 |  3 |  2
 230328 |     5 |     2 |  3 |  3 |  2 |  1 |  2
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I never thought to use `execute plpgsql`, not `execute sql`...

Comment: what is the purpose of `EXECUTE format( $x2$ ...`?.. why not `IF THEN END IF` without it?..

Comment: I have a feeling that this should be possible to solve without looping through timestamps, just don't know how...

Comment: please update the question excluding all not necessary info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    small_panel.*, c1, c2, c3
from
    small_panel
    left join (
        select
            dt,
            unnest(a_lotid) as lotid,
            unnest((select array_agg(a order by random()) from unnest(a) a(a))) as c1,
            unnest((select array_agg(a order by random()) from unnest(a) a(a))) as c2,
            unnest((select array_agg(a order by random()) from unnest(a) a(a))) as c3
        from
            (
                select
                    dt,
                    array_agg(lotid) a_lotid,
                    count(called is not null or null)::int as total_called
                from small_panel
                group by 1
            ) s
            cross join lateral (
                select
                    array_fill(1, array[total_called]) ||
                    array_fill(null::int, array[array_length(a_lotid, 1) - total_called])
            ) a(a)
    ) s using (dt, lotid)
```

Output

```
  gid   |  id  | lotid  | called | distance |         dt          | c1 | c2 | c3 
--------+------+--------+--------+----------+---------------------+----+----+----
 536596 |  207 |   2904 |        |  392.648 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00 |    |    |  1
 537409 | 1017 |   5453 |      1 |  190.071 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00 |  1 |  1 |   
 538417 | 2025 | 230328 |      1 |  69.9698 | 2009-06-05 12:40:00 |  1 |  1 |  1
 628826 |  207 |   2904 |      1 |  439.769 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00 |    |    |  1
 629637 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  226.278 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00 |  1 |  1 |   
 630647 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  387.914 | 2009-06-05 19:00:00 |    |    |   
 643377 |  207 |   2904 |      1 |  8.50651 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00 |    |    |  1
 644185 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  124.361 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00 |  1 |  1 |   
 645195 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  214.799 | 2009-06-05 20:00:00 |    |    |   
 670076 |  207 |   2904 |        |  135.042 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00 |    |    |  1
 670887 | 1017 |   5453 |      1 |  81.0408 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00 |  1 |  1 |   
 671896 | 2025 | 230328 |        |  193.953 | 2009-06-05 21:50:00 |    |    |   
 679781 |  207 |   2904 |        |  170.979 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00 |  1 |    |   
 680594 | 1017 |   5453 |        |  223.304 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00 |    |    |   
 681605 | 2025 | 230328 |      1 |  92.0443 | 2009-06-05 22:30:00 |    |  1 |  1
```

I do not understand the meaning of `calledZ` so I did not include it.

This is the dynamic function with no loops and no intermediary tables:

```
create or replace function ib_randomise_calls (_n int default 3)
returns void as $func$
begin
drop table if exists panel_000;
execute format($$
    create table panel_000 as
    select
        small_panel.*, %1$s
    from
        small_panel
        left join (
            select
                dt,
                unnest(a_lotid) as lotid, %2$s
            from
                (
                    select
                        dt,
                        array_agg(lotid) a_lotid,
                        count(called is not null or null)::int as total_called
                    from small_panel
                    group by 1
                ) s
                cross join lateral (
                    select
                        array_fill(1, array[total_called]) ||
                        array_fill(null::int, array[array_length(a_lotid, 1) - total_called])
                ) a(a)
        ) s using (dt, lotid)
    $$,
    (
        select string_agg(format('%s%s', a, i), ', ')
        from unnest(array_fill('called_'::text, array[_n])) with ordinality s (a, i)
    ),
    (
        select string_agg(format('%s%s', a, i), ', ')
        from unnest(array_fill('unnest((
                select array_agg(a order by random())
                from unnest(a) a(a)
            )) as called_'::text, array[_n])
        ) with ordinality s (a, i)
    )
);
end;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: This works! I add the final working dynamic version in the end of the question.

Comment: I am curious about this part: usually I avoid complex joins in favour of readability and control. But I am a researcher not DBA so my skill with joins is limited. But for a large input table, is the following correct : without the intermediate tables it's in memory and with it writes and reads? A d also what is faster?

Comment: A single execution is faster than a loop as the Postgresql planner can optimize for it. Joins are at the core of relational databases and all is done to make them as efficient as possible. Although there are other techniques well optimized (in Postgresql at least), in general avoiding joins is denying decades of database software development.

Comment: Point taken,  I shall try this on a big panel:)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Working dynamic function using  Clodoaldo Neto 's query:

```
DROP FUNCTION ib_randomise_calls(int);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ib_randomise_calls ( n INT DEFAULT 3 )
  RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
DECLARE mytext TEXT DEFAULT 'small_panel';
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_000;
  CREATE TABLE panel_000 AS ( SELECT * FROM small_panel  );
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'i: %', i;
    EXECUTE format( $x1$ ALTER TABLE panel_000 ADD COLUMN called_%1$s INT; $x1$, i);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS panel_i;
    CREATE TABLE panel_i AS (
      select
        small_panel.*, Ci
      from
        small_panel
        left join (
                    select
                      dt,
                      unnest(a_lotid) as lotid,
                      unnest((select array_agg(a order by random()) from unnest(a) a(a))) as Ci
                    from
                      (
                        select
                          dt,
                          array_agg(lotid) a_lotid,
                          count(called is not null or null)::int as total_called
                        from small_panel
                        group by 1 ORDER BY 1
                      ) s
                      cross join lateral (
                                 select
                                   array_fill(1, array[total_called]) ||
                                   array_fill(null::int, array[array_length(a_lotid, 1) - total_called])
                                 ) a(a)
                  ) s
        using (dt, lotid)
    );
    EXECUTE format(
        $x2$
          UPDATE panel_000 a SET called_%1$s = Ci from panel_i b where a.dt=b.dt and a.lotid = b.lotid;
        $x2$, i);
    mytext:=i;
  END LOOP ;
  RETURN mytext;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select ib_randomise_calls(5);
```